# Get the selected dropdown's value in spreadsheet in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: New Sheet] [image: Current Sheet]

I have searched a lot about this but no results so far.
My question is pretty simple, What are the possible ways to get a dropdown's(which i created with datavalidations) selected value without using onEdit() or any trigger in Google Script.
I know this might be a pretty simple or even dumb question, but I am a novice in google sheets and script.
Thanks for the help

**Edit:
These are the images of my sheet, I want to get the dropdown's value from the current sheet and then get the count of the `selected element's` frequency in new sheet and hence fill the count in the count column in the current sheet again.**

Code:

```
function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var currSheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myEdit')
.forSpreadsheet(currSheet)
.onEdit()
.create();
}

function myEdit(e){

  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();

  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();

  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();

  if(wsName ==="Math" && r > 1)   
    returnFun(e.value);    
}

function returnFun(selectedDropdown){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var currSheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var oss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(" Some id");
  var sheet = oss.getSheetByName(" Some Name "); 

// Here I check the selectedDropdown with a column of oss Spreadsheet 
// but the onEdit trigger keeps giving me error that I cant access that file
// this error only occurs when I use onEdit(), else the oss sheet works fine.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

Installable triggers *inherit authorization from the process that created them*. The `onOpen()` trigger you have is set to run **on the current spreadsheet** but at the same time it is creating an installable `onEdit()` trigger. This `onEdit()` trigger is later making use of **another spreadsheet**, for which you didn't authorize the permissions for.

Therefore, I suggest you create the `onEdit()` trigger by going to *Current project's triggers* -> *Add trigger* and choose the `myEdit` function for the trigger to run on. I also suggest you to skip the `onOpen()` trigger as you are only using it for creating the other trigger.

#### Snippet

```
function myEdit(e){
    var activeCell = e.range;
    var val = activeCell.getValue();
    var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
    var r = activeCell.getRow();
    var c = activeCell.getColumn();
    if (wsName === "Math" && r > 1)
        returnFun(e.value);
}

function returnFun(selectedDropdown){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
    var currSheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var oss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(" Some id");
    var sheet = oss.getSheetByName(" Some Name ");

    // Here I check the selectedDropdown with a column of oss Spreadsheet 
    // but the onEdit trigger keeps giving me error that I cant access that file
    // this error only occurs when I use onEdit(), else the oss sheet works fine.
}
```

#### Reference

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: I want a dynamic solution for this. This will give me the value for a single run. What i want is whenever user changes the dropdown I get the changed or dynamic value. bcoz I have to perform 'count frequency from another column' operation on the resultant value from this dropdown making our sheet dynamic.

Comment: set an onEdit trigger

Comment: i tried onEdit trigger too. but i have to perform the said operation on different spreadsheet and onedit() keeps giving error on "getSheetById()" (even on installed triggers).  @JamesD

Comment: what should be by next bet?

Comment: That should work fine, are you sure you are using the correct ID?

Comment: Hello @JustCurious, so what exactly is the issue with an `onEdit()` trigger?

Comment: yes im sure, bcoz Im doing lot of other stuff with the same id too.

Comment: as i said, onEdit() keeps giving me this error **Require auth permission** . i tried using installed trigger too, but the error persists. thats why i want some other way to get the dropdown value dynamically. @ale13

Comment: Install the trigger and try running the script first time from the debugger to force authorization of it?

Comment: can try that, will let u know.@JamesD

Comment: Hello @JustCurious, do you have permission for the spreadsheet in question? Cheers!

Comment: Yes i have the editable access and permissions for the spreadsheet. @ale13

Comment: @JustCurious, is it your spreadsheet? Did you create the trigger yourself?

Comment: Yes i created a trigger like ```ScriptApp.newTrigger('myEdit')....``` and then made a ```func myEdit(e){}```. But still not working @ale13

Comment: @JustCurious, can you edit your question and include the code you have used and provide all the information needed as well? That would be of great help in order to be able to help you properly :) Cheers!

Comment: I have provided enough info about my problem here. Any help would be appreciated. @ale13

Comment: Although I did try the GUI method to install trigger before. But this worked. Thanks alot for your constant help. One more thing, the trigger took a lot of time to execute and in the triggers console menu(after doing all the work) it said failed. Any reason you might think of? @ale13

Comment: Hello @JustCurious! I'm glad it worked! The issue was related to the `onOpen()` trigger so that's why it was not working then :) Cheers!

Comment: About the trigger question @JustCurious, you will have to check the exact message you are receiving and try to diagnose the issue.